# Sort list of wave files based on format info

Tags: c#, windows, audio, wav

I have a whole bunch of .wav files which are to be concatenated by a program , based on a list of file names supplied to it. 
The program kept turning legible audio files into garbage .. upon investigation using audacity I realised that the files have all been recorded on different devices some in mono format , some in stereo, at different sampling rates etc.

To be able to convert these files into the required common sampling rate- all in stereo etc, I need to run a few batch conversions in audacity.
For this I need to files separated out into groups with same sampling rate and same number of tracks etc.
I wrote a utility program in c# that can scan a folder that has all these files and give me a comma separated txt file with the file name and the formatting info.
I am reading the file stream into a bytearray , but while interpreting the formatting info- I think the program is somehow adding extra 0s at the end of each format info,

What is going wrong ? Any help is appreciated.
Relevant Code below -

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@pathString))
{
    fileLine += "[Resource Name ], [File Size], [Format Chunk Size], [isPCM ? ], [Num of Channels], [Sample Rate], [(Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8],[BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8], [Bits PerSample], [Data Size ]" + Environment.NewLine;
    file.WriteLine(fileLine);
    fileLine = "";
    for (i = 0; i < FileNames.Length; i++)
    {
      string fname = "";
      fname = FileNames[i];
      fileLine += "'" + fname + "',";
      Byte[] resBytesArr = ByteArrFromFileStream(FileNames[i]);
      if (resBytesArr.Length > 44)
      {
      // file size 
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[4] + resBytesArr[5] + resBytesArr[6] + resBytesArr[7] ;
      // fmt size 
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[16] + resBytesArr[17] + resBytesArr[18] + resBytesArr[19] ;
      // format ? 1 for PCM  
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[20] + resBytesArr[21];
      // num of channels
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[22] + resBytesArr[23] ;
      // sample rate
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[24] + resBytesArr[25] + resBytesArr[26] + resBytesArr[27] ;
      //(Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[28] + resBytesArr[29] + resBytesArr[30] + resBytesArr[31] ;
      //(BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8.1 - 8 bit mono2 - 8 bit stereo/16 bit mono4 - 16 bit stereo
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[32] + resBytesArr[33] ;
      //Bits per sample
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[34] + resBytesArr[35] ;
      // data size 
      fileLine += "," + resBytesArr[40] + resBytesArr[41] + resBytesArr[42] + resBytesArr[43] ;
      // end of info for one resource, move to next
      fileLine += Environment.NewLine;
      file.WriteLine(fileLine);
      fileLine = "";
      file.WriteLine(".....done." + Environment.NewLine);
      }
      else
      {
        file.WriteLine("Byte Array seems invalid for " + fname + Environment.NewLine);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that array members (including byte[]) are automatically initialized to the default initial value for the array type. Byte[] arrays are initialized to 0x0. Without really seeing what's going on in:

```
ByteArrFromFileStream(...)
```

I'd have to guess, and my guess is that on some of your files, the actual application that originally encoded the binary stream created a standard block-sized malloc() memory allocation buffer.  When the actual encoding of the stream was completed, the length of the stream fell several bytes short of the last memory allocation. So when the file is written to disk, a bunch of 0x0's get written out with it.

As a side note, when using any of the 'Stream' types be sure to be careful about who and what closes down the stream, for further reading I recommend a perusal of this article:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985010.aspx